# Define several members dynamically in class/interface using F#

Tags: dynamic, types, interface, f#

I'm working on small program using F# just for the personal training and got some moment, which I can't solve.

I'm describing some interface:

```
type IСalculations =
    abstract member Add : int * int -> int
    abstract member Subtract : int * int -> int
    abstract member Multiply : int * int -> int
    abstract member Divide : int * int -> int
```

As you can see, the member signature besides the name is the same.

Am I able to do using F# the next (now will be **pseudo-code**):

```
let names = [ "Add", "Subtract", "Multiply", "Divide" ];
let ICalculations = new interface;

foreach ( name in names ) {
    ICalculations[ name ] : int * int -> int
}
```

The aim is NOT to repeat for each member the signature `int * int -> int`

Is it possible?

Comment: Consider if you can model your problems in F# *without* interfaces: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34028711/126014

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot define interface method types after the interface declaration. 
But you can define for example Dictionary, containing functions of your type:

```
open System.Collections.Generic    
type Ops = Add | Subtract | Multiply | Divide
let pseudoInterface = Dictionary<Ops, int * int -> int>()

// Then somewhere in your program you could define this "methods"
pseudoInterface.[Add] <- fun (i, j) -> i + j
pseudoInterface.[Subtract] <- fun (i, j) -> i - j // etc...
```

Or you can define type alias for function type for brevity:

```
type Op = int * int -> int
type IСalculations =
    abstract member Add : Op    
    abstract member Subtract : Op
    abstract member Multiply : Op
    abstract member Divide : Op
```

Answer (score 1):

The only syntax for declaring an interface is :

```
// Interface declaration:
[ attributes ]
type interface-name =
   [ interface ]     [ inherit base-interface-name ...]
     abstract member1 : [ argument-types1 -> ] return-type1
     abstract member2 : [ argument-types2 -> ] return-type2
     ...
   [ end ]
```

In the second line of your pseudo-code :

```
let ICalculations = new interface;
```

you wish to use a let binding or equivalent.
Unfortunately, let bindings only associate an identifier with a value or a function and not with a type or an interface.
So I am afraid there is no way.
Other functional languages than F#, such as Idris, can do it.
If you are only bothered by the verbosity of having to repeat int*int->int, you can define a type alias like so :

```
module T =
  type Op = int * int -> int

type IСalculations =
    abstract member Add : T.Op
    abstract member Subtract : T.Op
    abstract member Multiply : T.Op
    abstract member Divide : T.Op
```